# Format CSS Content image

Tags: css

I would like to vertically center the image I am adding via the CSS `content` property. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F37pV/13/)

Comment: set vertical align:sub; in #foo::after

Comment: @SvenBieder - That doesn't work.

Comment: for me it works, but when you use ie you must set a doctype to get it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do it as a background image? Looking at the example code below the positioning is handled by the last two parts.

```
#bar {
  background: url(http://goo.gl/XWguD) no-repeat right 50%;
  padding: 3px 40px 3px 0;         
}
```

:after is not supported < IE7 ([see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3aafter)) where as background images are supported everywhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/F37pV/20/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding an element via content? Why not use `background-image`?